# Print array line by line in a here doc

Tags: bash, shell-script

I currently have the following here doc

```
message=`cat <<-EOF
Test data:
Test data 1:
"${Test_data_array[@]}"
EOF`
echo "$message"
```

Is there a way to get the array to display multi-line per entry like this line but within the here doc?

```
printf '%s\n' "${Test_data_array[@]}"
```

Comment: `IFS=$'\n'; cat <<<"${array[*]}"`

Comment: This works fine on its own but when i plugged this into the here doc, it just prints the expression

Comment: I dont follow you, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IFS` and `[*]` to print the array:

```bash
OLDIFS="${IFS}"
IFS=$'\n'

message=`cat <<-EOF
Test data:
Test data 1:
${Test_data_array[*]}
EOF`

IFS="${OLDIFS}"

echo "$message"
```

Comment: Also drops trailing null fields.

Answer (score 2):

```
message=`cat <<-EOF
Test data:
Test data 1:
$(printf "%s\n" "${Test_data_array[@]}")
EOF`

echo "$message"
```

Comment: Drops trailing null fields...

Answer (score 1):

```
IFS='
'; message="\
Test data:
Test data 1:
${Test_data_array[*]}
"
```